# Publishing JAR to Maven Central with Travis-CI

Tags: maven, makefile, travis-ci, nexus

I'm working on a project hosted at Github. Currently, the project gets built by a Makefile, and it has travis-ci integration.

I want to configure travis-ci such that it will publish the resulting JAR file to Maven Central. What are the necessary steps for this task?

Comment: Why are you using a Makefile for a Java project?

Comment: Because of the nature of the project, most of the java code is auto-generated from some meta-language. The thing is, the meta language can also be converted to Javascript, Python etc, so instead of using a separate build tool for each intermediate language, we decided to just stick to makefiles for everything.

Comment: So Ok so far. But you have now generated Java code which needs to be compiled and packaged which can be done via Maven afterwards you can deploy those artifacts to Maven Central using the appropriate credentials. See http://central.sonatype.org/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this will be very hard to do without Maven. So you first need to switch your build system to Maven. After you are able to build your project successfully follow the directions [here](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2015/01/08/deploy-to-maven-central-repository/) to get credentials for publishing to maven central.